# Entity Framework With Read Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using EF 6 for a project and I am new to EF. For this particular project, we used an existing database and stored procedures where we could. I have one stored procedure that is bringing in more columns of data than the model has. We had worked around using that stored procedure, but now the data that it is returning has been requested again. I am not sure of the best way to implement this, so I am turning here for help.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure dbo.procGetMainInvoices
  @Division CHAR(5),
  @CustNum  CHAR(6)
AS
SELECT  i.InvoiceNumber,
        i.Division,
        i.CustomerNumber,
        i.InvoiceType,
        i.InvoiceDate,
        i.DueDate,
        i.AmountDue,
        (SELECT COUNT(trn.InvoiceNumber)
         FROM   Invoice trn
         WHERE  trn.InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
         AND    trn.Division = i.Division
         AND    trn.CustomerNumber = i.CustomerNumber) as TransactionCount
FROM    Invoice i
WHERE   i.Division = @Division
AND     i.CustomerNumber = @CustNum
AND     i.InvoiceStatus = 'O'
AND     i.ItemSequence = 0
AND     i.ItemLine = 0
ORDER BY i.InvoiceDate,
         i.InvoiceNumber
```

As you can see, the last column being selected is a count. I need to get that data added to my existing invoice model. I need it done efficiently because I could be reading hundreds or thousands of records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by converting the stored procedure to a view. Then binding my DBContext to the view. I had to create a new model that included the fields in the view, but it did give me the flexibility that I needed to be able to filter my results to same degree as the stored procedure.